# Reading old HDF5 stores created by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

I'm having some trouble reading and old HDF5 file that I made with pandas in python 2.7.

At the time I was using the `to_hdf` method to append groups to the file (e.g. `db.to_hdf('File.h5', 'groupNameA', mode='a', data_columns=True, format='table')`)

Now when I open the store and get the keys of the groups I find that each one has a slash added to the name (`'/groupNameA'` in the example above). Attempting to access those groups with `store['/groupNameA']`, `store.select('/groupNameA')`, etc. produces `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string`. Getting that error seems correct (slashes should not be used in these keys) but that doesn't help me get my data into a python 3 environment.

If there's a way to get around this problem in python 3, that'd be great.

Alternatively, I can still load the data in my 2.7 environment. So changing the code for writing the store so that slashes don't get added would probably solve the issue as well.